# Virtualenv Package Install and Import

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm new to Python, but decided to try out the Pyramid web application framework using [their tutorial](http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/python_setup.html). I modified some of the steps to bring it up-to-date with what I understand to be the proper way to handle this with modern tools.

As context, `virtualenv` and my `python` (version 3.4) are installed on my Mac (Yosemite) with macports.

This is what I did:

```
$ virtualenv swapenv
Using base prefix '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in swapenv/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in swapenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ source swapenv/bin/activate
(swapenv)$ pip install pyramid
... (successful install of pyramid with some warnings) ...
```

So far, so good. Now I try to see if I can verify the install, see that python can't find it. I bang my head for an hour. Then think to try `python3`:

```
(swapenv)$ python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 11:45:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyramid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyramid'
>>> exit()
(swapenv)$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 11:45:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyramid
>>>
```

So if I use `python3` it works but `python` does not. I went to verify those installs:

```
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ pwd
/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/bin
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ which python
/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/bin/python
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ which python3
/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/bin/python3
```

Ok, so pointing to different places, right? Or not...?

```
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ cd /Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/bin
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ ls -la python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 nateford  staff      9 Nov 14 16:25 python -> python3.4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 nateford  staff      9 Nov 14 16:25 python3 -> python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nateford  staff  13180 Nov 14 16:25 python3.4
```

Why is it that using `python` has a different result than using `python3`? Is there a way to diagnose the difference? Is there a way to correct the difference (I have no intention of using python 2, so would prefer everything to point to `python3`).

UPDATE: Per a comment request the following is outputted by the `python -m site` command

```
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/bin',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webapp-0.1-py3.4.egg',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/nateford/Library/Python/3.4' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/nateford/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
(swapenv)rook-4:bin nateford$ python3 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/bin',
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/lib/python34.zip',
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/lib/python3.4',
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
    '/Users/nateford/experiments/pyramid/swapenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/nateford/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/nateford/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

Comment: What output do you get with `python -m site` and `python3 -m site`?

Comment: Can you post the output of `which python` and `which python3`?

Comment: @vikramis The output of those commands is included in the original posted question.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I updated the question with the output you requested. I don't understand why `sys.path` would be different for those two invocations!

Comment: Could it be that `python` is pointing to the global `python3.4` whereas `python3` (within the virtualenv) is pointing to the local `python3.4` installation (as part of the virtualenv)? That seems to be happening. When you installed Python 3, did you do the command that MacPorts mentions at the end to replace the system Python with the newly installed Python 3? If so, you shouldn't have done that as that messes up your system Python installation. `python` should always point to the default system installation of Python, all other installations should be alongside it.

Comment: That does seem to be the case, @SimeonVisser. There doesn't seem to be an easy way on Mac to confirm where the symlink is going, but I did replace via macports the active python. Strange that there is no visibility into what is being executed! Happy to give you credit if you want to create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that where your `python` and `python3` are pointed at the creation of the virtual environment matters. The first step to solve this is to make sure that MacPorts has the correct Python version selected:

```
sudo port select --set python python34
```

Then create the virtual environment as normal. This ensures that the python that `pip`, the `python` alias and the `bin` links that the virtual environment creates are all pointed in the same direction.